# Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli error

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
include_once("php/db_connects.php");

$tbl_status = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS status ( 
                id INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
                osid INT(11) NOT NULL,
                account_name VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
                author VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,
                type ENUM('a','b','c') NOT NULL,
                data TEXT NOT NULL,
                postdate DATETIME NOT NULL,
                PRIMARY KEY (id) 
                )"; 
$query = mysqli_query($tbl_status, $db_connects); 
if ($query === TRUE) {
    echo "<h3>status table created </h3>"; 
} else {
    echo "<h3>status table NOT created </h3>"; 
}
```

I keep getting the mysqli error. Im prtty sure that i'm not using msql in my php.

Comment: i just tested the query [>>here<<](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/66c62) and it worked fine.

Comment: Karthik, please accept the answer that has helped you solving the question.

Answer (score 1):

change this

```
$query = mysqli_query($tbl_status, $db_connects);
```

to

```
$query = mysqli_query($db_connects, $tbl_status);
```

example **mysqli_query( mysqli $link , string $query )**

Comment: I tried this. But i'm still recieving the error: Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given in...

Comment: @Karthik where is your `$db_connects` defined?

Comment: It's defined in my db_connects.php file

Comment: Actually I figured it out. It was defined as db_connect while i was calling it as db_connects.

Answer (score 0):

The signature for `mysqli_query` is:

```
mixed mysqli_query ( mysqli $link , string $query [, int $resultmode = MYSQLI_STORE_RESULT ] )
```

Assuming `$db_connects` is the variable storing the result of `mysqli_connect`, you need to flip your arguments to fit:

```
mysqli_query($db_connects, $tbl_status);
```

[mysqli_query documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.query.php)